# method gives date time conversion exception while upload to database on server side asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, webmethod

I created a web services which take string variable which is in a datetime format like '17/08/2018 16:00'. Before updating it to server side i convert it to a datetime format and use datetime variable 
here is my code

```
 [WebMethod]
public string AddBanquetOrder(string orderMenustring, int HotelId, int CustomerId, int PackageID,int PackageQuentity, double TotalAmount, string Extra, string ExpectedDate)
{
    try
    {
        DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(ExpectedDate);
        string str = new WSBanquetOrder().AddOrder(orderMenustring, HotelId, CustomerId,PackageID,PackageQuentity,TotalAmount,Extra,dt);
        str = str.Substring(0, str.Length - 1);

        return str;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return "0";
    }
}
```

on Local Host it work finely but when i upload it on server i exception at the time string to datetime conversion
my input is
[input date string is - 16/08/2018 16:00](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IolKQ.png)
on local host i get response as

```
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">ORD2018081639</string>
```

on server it catch exception error as

```
    <string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
at System.DateTimeParse.Parse(String s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles styles) at System.Convert.ToDateTime(String value) at WSAndroid.AddBanquetOrder(String orderMenustring, Int32 HotelId, Int32 CustomerId, Int32 PackageID, Int32 PackageQuentity, Double TotalAmount, String Extra, String ExpectedDate) in e:x~\wwwroot\App_Code\WebService\WSAndroid.cs:line 90
</string>
```

Comment: **"string ExpectedDate"** There's your problem right there. **Do not** pass strings as dates to the database. Instead, pass an instance of the DateTime struct. That will solve all the formatting issues.

Comment: I agree with Zohar. Converting strings to DateTime often causes problems. Additionally: Also do not pass strings dates from client to server. If it works on localhost, but not on the web server, I guess the web server uses another format of date and time as your client.

Comment: i changed input datetime format from dd/mm/yyyy h:m to yyyy/mm/dd h:m and now its working

Comment: the issue is in this line `string str = new WSBanquetOrder().AddOrder(orderMenustring, HotelId, CustomerId,PackageID,PackageQuentity,TotalAmount,Extra,dt);
` and not in date conversion... make sure `AddOrder` is datetime too

Comment: *"i changed input datetime format..."* And it **will break** as soon as someone changes **local settings** on the server. If you really must use string literals (**you don't!**), at least use **ISO 8106 (`yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss`).** This string representation format is guaranteed to always be interpreted correctly by SQL Server.